# Lambda function does not update array from outer scope

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

As you know, "Local variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". So I have the following code

```java
List<Airline> filteredAirlines = new ArrayList<>();
JavaRDD<Company> flightCompanyJavaRDD = rdd.map(f -> {
      ......
      results = foo(f);
      filteredAirlines.addAll(results.getFilteredAirlines());
      System.out.println(results.getFilteredAirlines().size());
      Company convertedCompanyResult = convert(results);
      return convertedCompanyResult;
});
......
System.out.println(filteredArilines.size());
```

Line 1 printed `1` and line 2 printed `0`. It seems the list `filteredArilines` was not being filled. Any ideas why? And how can I get the values in the lambda expression available outside? Thanks.

Comment: The closure inside `map` does not actually use `f`, which represents one object from the `rdd` collection.  Since you are not using `f`, nor generating an `Airline` object, therefore the lambda expression makes no sense.

Comment: Totally agree but maybe its `foo()` is some `foo(f)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make this clear. the foo() should be foo(f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your lambda is called a *closure* since it is capturing something from outer scope (here your array).
2. It is totally discouraged to use a closure that captures objects that are intended to be modified. It is because it might only work in *local mode*: Indeed in *cluster mode* after serialization/deserialization, each captured object will have a version of itself living independently on each JVM. I point you to Spark's doc about [*Understanding closures*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka)
3. The cleanest way to do what you want may be to use [*Accumulators*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators)

Comment: Use Accumulators as you suggested. It works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: Well done, I edited the title of your question to make it more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `rdd` is and what `rdd.map()` does, but the fact that you pass to it a lambda expression doesn't mean that it is executed immediately (or at all).

Hence, when you print `filteredArilines.size()` in the last line of your snippet, the lambda expression probably hasn't executed yet, so the `List` is still empty.

Comment: Is there a way that I force some code run after rdd.map() is done?

Answer (score 0):

You could map your result directly to the List like this:

```
List<Airline> filteredAirlines = rdd.map(f -> {
      ......
      results = foo();
      System.out.println(results.getFilteredAirlines().size());
      return results.getFilteredAirlines();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If `{ ... }` does not use `f`, then what is the point of the lambda expression?

Comment: Thats right. I didn't thought of the case that he doesn't even use `f`.